# Is it correct to make an object for Console.Readlines input?

Tags: c#, object, console

i just started learning C# and all these Classes, Objects and Methods still confuse me. So i came up with this piece of code, its working fine but i got the feeling i do things that i shouldnt do. Can some C# experts have a look over it?

Is this a good way to take Input and then work with it?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    input crInput = new input();
    Console.WriteLine(crInput.evalInput(Console.ReadLine()));
}

private class input
{
    public string InputString { get; set; }

    public string evalInput(string _input)
    {
        string result = "";

        string input = _input;

        if (input == "1")
        {
            result = "1";
        }
        else if (input == "2")
        {
            result = "2";
        }
        else if (input == "3")
        {
            result = "3";
        }
        else
        {
            result = "NOTHING";
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  You basically just repeat a users input back to them most of the time.

Comment: This isn't a code review site, but a I'll give you a pointer anyway.  You need to work on your casing conventions.  Classes and methods should always be PascalCased.  Your method parameters should never be prefixed with a `_`, typically that is only ever seen in private class level members (and even then its debated if its proper).  Secondly do you really want to instantiate an object just to verify input?  Couldn't that be a static method of a class?  Your input evaluation relies on no instance data so it likely should be static.  Third, why even bother having the `result` variable?

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback although this isnt a review site. I'll work on  my casing conventions! So using an Object to verify input is indeed not a good manner. So in what "kind" of class would you put the method? Helps me better understanding classes/methods, .

Comment: @David David, check my post, may it help you

Answer (score 1):

As I see in your code, several details can be fixed:
First, you can simplify the CRInput assignment by substituting the name of the class for the keyword var: `var CRInput = new Input();` in C# **var** supports almost all types of data.

Another thing to take into account is that the names of the classes should start with Capital, this is the correct way.

Another thing is that you do not have to create another `string input` if you already have one previously.

The **switch** keyword simplifies the repetitive use of else if you can see, and it is recommended that each sentence have its own line.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //var supports almost all types of data, which simplifies the object declaration process
    var CRInput = new Input();
    Console.WriteLine(CRInput.EvalInput(Console.ReadLine()));
}

//Class names must start with capitals
private class Input
{
    public string InputString { get; set; }

    public string EvalInput(string input)
    {
        //Initialize result with the value -> ""
        string result = string.Empty;

        //The switch structure simplifies and shortens the repetitive use of else if
        switch (input)
        {
            //if
            case "1":
               result = "1"; 
               break;

            //else if
            case "2": 
               result = "2"; 
               break;

            //else if
            case "3": 
               result = "3"; 
               break;

            //else
            default: 
               result = "NOTHING";
               break;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: @maccettura I only did it so that the applicant understood what I did, but I already edited it, thanks for the data, I will keep it in mind in my future posts

Comment: Your answer still contains code that has multiple lines of code _in-line_.  Look at your `switch` cases, `result = ...` and `break;` should be on their own lines.  Writing code all on the same line like you have done will lead to bugs and hard to read code.

Comment: @maccettura It's okay like that?

Comment: Yes, now it is easier to read and debug.  Can you see why this is better and easier to read and maintain?

Comment: @maccettura 
Because as each sentence has its own line, it can be separated visually from its adjacent sentence

Comment: Yes, while programming our eyes are trained to look at lines.  If we have random semi-colons (`;`) in the middle of our lines they may get overlooked and lead to confusing or hard to maintain code.

Comment: @maccettura Oh, it helps me a lot, thank you very much for the data

Comment: You should still provide some explanation in your answer.  Just posting code is usually not helpful.  Take some time to explain why your code is different not just in the code comments but in a nice easy to read paragraph or two.  You will likely attract more upvotes that way.

Comment: @maccettura ok, give me a moment

Comment: @maccettura I think that in this case, instead of one or two paragraphs, separating the sections by section will make it easier to read and understand; Check my post and tell me if it's okay